# Apply style on immediate parent element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply style on the parent selector based on the class specified in the child. I know this can be done in Javascript but I am trying to find a solution which can be applied on my css file. I tried:

```
div < .active {
    background:red;
}
```

but it selects/applies style only the child. I want the style to be applicable on the div parent here for example.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is No parent selector in CSS as of today. So the answer is **No you cannot do it in CSS**.. JavaScript is the only option

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
div > .active {
    background:red;
}
```

it is better to mention element also such as

```
div > div.active {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: sorry this is just to set the child element there is no way for the other way around